# I cannot search with ElasticSearch. Tire::Search::SearchRequestFailed: 503

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, elasticsearch, tire

I have a method for search in model:

```
def self.search params
  tire.search do
    query { string params[:query], default_operator: "AND" }
  end
end
```

in the terminal, I see:

```
[REQUEST FAILED] curl -X GET "http://localhost:9200/products/product/_search?pretty=true" -d '{"query":{"query_string":{"query":null}}}'
Tire::Search::SearchRequestFailed: 503 : {"error":"SearchPhaseExecutionException[Failed to execute phase [query], all shards failed]","status":503}
from /home/naumenko/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p550/gems/tire-0.3.12/lib/tire/search.rb:72:in `perform'
```

I'm using Ruby 1.9.3; Rails 3.0.14

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `params[:query]` is null, whereas elasticsearch is obviously expecting a string.

In addition it looks like you are running a very old version of tire. Even the latest version of tire (which has been retired) doesn't officially support elasticsearch 1.0+ so you may run into additional compatibility problems.